# Inner join with multiples tables

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I want to show multiples articles in the "feed" like the facebook. I got this tables:

- LINKS (LINKS SHARED BY PAGES) {LINK_PAGE_ID, LINK_AUTHORS}
- LINKS_SHARE (LINKS SHARED BY USERS) {LINK_SHARE_AUTHORS_ID, LINK_SHARES_LINK_ID}
- FOLLOWERS_PAGE (FOLLOWERS OF PAGE) {FOLLOWERS_PAGE_PAGE_ID, FOLLOWERS_PAGE_AUTHORS_ID}
- FOLLOWERS (FOLLOWERS OF USERS) {AUTHORS_ID, FOLLOWER_ID}
- AUTHORS (PROFILE OF USERS) {AUTHORS_ID}
- PAGES (PROFILE OF PAGES) {PAGE_ID}
- CATEGORIES (CATEGORY OF ARTICLE)

I need to transform this query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * 
    FROM LINKS 
   INNER JOIN FOLLOWERS_PAGE ON FOLLOWERS_PAGE_PAGE_ID = LINK_PAGE_ID 
   INNER JOIN PAGES ON PAGE_ID = FOLLOWERS_PAGE_PAGE_ID 
   INNER JOIN CATEGORIES ON CATEGORY_ID = PAGE_CATEGORIES 
    WHERE FOLLOWERS_PAGE_AUTHORS_ID = 1555 ORDER BY LINK_DATE DESC) 
WHERE ROWNUM <= 3
```

How I can do it?

Comment: It's not clear what do you want to see as a result. Could you add some example of input and output data, please?

Comment: Transform to what?